# Main Activity asking for a Constructor - Second Activity Not In Manifest file

Tags: java, android

```
  enter code here


  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.example.newuser.applicationtwo">

  <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"

    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:screenOrientation="landscape"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
   >
    <activity

        android:name=".MainActivity"
       android:screenOrientation="landscape"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
    </activity>
    <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </application>
    <activity android:name=".SecondActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".ThirdActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".FourthActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".FifthActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".SixthActivity" />
    </manifest>



    -----------------------------------------------------------------------


   package com.example.newuser.applicationtwo;

    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.ImageButton;
    import static android.content.ContentValues.TAG;

  public class MainActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener 
{

  private ImageButton playBtn, multiplayerBtn, settingsBtn;

  public MainActivity(ImageButton playBtn, ImageButton multiplayerBtn) {
    this.playBtn = playBtn;
    this.multiplayerBtn = multiplayerBtn;
  }


  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {


        case R.id.playBtn:
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), 
    SecondActivity.class);

            startActivity(i);
            onClick(playBtn);
            Log.d(TAG, "Play Button Move");

            break;

        case R.id.TopicBtn8:
            Intent j = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), 
  ThirdActivity.class);

            startActivity(j);
            onClick(multiplayerBtn);
            Log.d(TAG, "Multiplayer Button Move");

            break;
        case R.id.settingsBtn:
            Intent k = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), 
    SixthActivity.class);

            startActivity(k);
            onClick(settingsBtn);
            Log.d(TAG, "Settings Button Move");

            break;
    }
  }
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    playBtn = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.playBtn);
    multiplayerBtn = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.multiplayerBtn);
    settingsBtn = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.settingsBtn);

    playBtn.setOnClickListener(MainActivity.this);
    multiplayerBtn.setOnClickListener(MainActivity.this);
    settingsBtn.setOnClickListener(MainActivity.this);



   ------------------------------------------------------------------------


   package com.example.newuser.applicationtwo;

 import android.app.Activity;
 import android.content.Intent;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
 import android.util.Log;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.widget.Button;

  import static android.content.ContentValues.TAG;

  class SecondActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements 
   View.OnClickListener {

 private Button topic1Btn, topic2Btn, topic3Btn, topic4Btn, topic5Btn, 
 topic6Btn, topic7Btn, topic8Btn;

 public SecondActivity(Button topic1Btn, Button topic2Btn, Button topic3Btn, 
  Button topic4Btn,
                      Button topic5Btn, Button topic6Btn, Button topic7Btn, 
   Button topic8Btn) {
    this.topic1Btn = topic1Btn;
    this.topic2Btn = topic2Btn;
    this.topic3Btn = topic3Btn;
    this.topic4Btn = topic4Btn;
    this.topic5Btn = topic5Btn;
    this.topic6Btn = topic6Btn;
    this.topic7Btn = topic7Btn;
    this.topic8Btn = topic8Btn;

  }

  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {


        case R.id.topic1Btn:
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), 
  SixthActivity.class);

            startActivity(i);
            onClick(topic1Btn);
            Log.d(TAG, "Topic 1 Button Clicked");

            break;

        case R.id.topic2Btn:
            Intent j = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), 
   SixthActivity.class);

            startActivity(j);
            onClick(topic2Btn);
            Log.d(TAG, "Topic 2 Button Clicked");

            break;
        case R.id.topic3Btn:
            Intent k = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), 
    SixthActivity.class);

            startActivity(k);
            onClick(topic3Btn);
            Log.d(TAG, "Topic 3 Button Move");

            break;

        case R.id.topic4Btn:
            Intent l = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), 
   SixthActivity.class);

            startActivity(l);
            onClick(topic4Btn);
            Log.d(TAG, "Topic 4 Button Move");

            break;
        case R.id.topic5Btn:
            Intent m = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), 
    SixthActivity.class);

            startActivity(m);
            onClick(topic5Btn);
            Log.d(TAG, "Topic 5 Button Clicked");

            break;

        case R.id.topic6Btn:
            Intent n = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), 
    SixthActivity.class);
            startActivity(n);
            onClick(topic6Btn);
            Log.d(TAG, "Topic 6 Button Clicked");

            break;
        case R.id.topic7Btn:
            Intent o = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), 
    SixthActivity.class);

            startActivity(o);
            onClick(topic7Btn);
            Log.d(TAG, "Topic 7 Button Move");

            break;

        case R.id.topic8Btn:
            Intent p = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), 
     SixthActivity.class);

            startActivity(p);
            onClick(topic8Btn);
            Log.d(TAG, "Topic 8 Button Move");

            break;
    }
  }

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);

    topic1Btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.topic1Btn);
    topic2Btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.topic2Btn);
    topic3Btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.topic3Btn);
    topic4Btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.topic4Btn);
    topic5Btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.topic5Btn);
    topic6Btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.topic6Btn);
    topic7Btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.topic7Btn);
    topic8Btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.topic8Btn);

    topic1Btn.setOnClickListener(SecondActivity.this);
    topic2Btn.setOnClickListener(SecondActivity.this);
    topic3Btn.setOnClickListener(SecondActivity.this);
    topic4Btn.setOnClickListener(SecondActivity.this);
    topic5Btn.setOnClickListener(SecondActivity.this);
    topic6Btn.setOnClickListener(SecondActivity.this);
    topic7Btn.setOnClickListener(SecondActivity.this);
    topic8Btn.setOnClickListener(SecondActivity.this);


    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), 
  SixthActivity.class);

    startActivity(intent);
  }
  }

----------------------------------------------------
```

I wonder if anyone can help? I am trying to build an quiz application and I
am having a problem with the main activity in the manifest file. It seems 
to be asking for a constructor and when I run the code it is telling me the 
following:Error running SecondActivity: The activity 'SecondActivity' is 
not declared in AndroidManifest.xml . Not sure how I would change this as
MainActivity or what else to add for the SecondActivity, unfortunately
reading through similar questions on MainActivity I cannot resolve it.

I attach the Manifest file and both the MainActivity and the SecondActivity

Comment: Thanks guys for coming back. I adjusted the manifest file but then had both MainActivity and SecondActivity errors  saying there were no default constructors? I have added a couple of non-usable empty constructors to each activity i.e. public MainActivity () {}  and it now runs.

Answer (score 1):

Move

```
</application>*
```

right before

```
</manifest>
```

because now only first activity is in < application > scope

Answer (score 0):

First **remove all constructor which is not needed here** and **you are not adding all activity under application tag in manifest** also **you defining the launcher filter out of activity tag add it under activity tag**, change manifest as below

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.example.newuser.applicationtwo">

  <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:screenOrientation="landscape"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
   >
    <activity
      android:name=".MainActivity"
      android:screenOrientation="landscape"
      android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
      android:label="@string/app_name">
      <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>


    <activity android:name=".SecondActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".ThirdActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".FourthActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".FifthActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".SixthActivity" />
     </application>
    </manifest>
```

I also recommend you to go through basic android development tutorial 
https://developer.android.com/training/index.html

Answer (score 0):

`activity` tags belong inside the `application` tag.

This should work:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
package="com.example.newuser.applicationtwo">
<application
android:allowBackup="true"
android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"

android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
android:screenOrientation="landscape"
android:supportsRtl="true">
<activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:screenOrientation="landscape"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    android:label="@string/app_name">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>

    <activity android:name=".SecondActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".ThirdActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".FourthActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".FifthActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".SixthActivity" />
</application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: what about intent filter?

Answer (score 0):

Appart the fakt that all the activities you declare in your androidmanifest file, should be included in the `<application> </application>` tag, also if you want to start one exact activity first (meaning that when the app launches that exact activity will start first, for example if you want a logo image, create an activity for that) , you can change the category name to LAUNCHER, and if you want it not to be the first activity starting when the application launches, put it to DEFAULT like this:

```
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
```